# Why Do Not Disturb is not activated in Xiaomi devices?

Tags: android, xiaomi, do-not-disturb

I am setting the interruption filter using this code:

```
NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
myNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY);
```

It works very well in every device, but, for some reason it doesn't in **Xiaomi** devices using Android 9. **Do Not Disturb mode is not activated** in those devices. It remains unchanged. If I ask the device what is the current interruption it answers with a value of 5. Which is an unknown and not documented value in Android Developer as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getCurrentInterruptionFilter()).

```
int iCurrentInterruption = oNotificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter();
```

iCurrentInterruption has a value of 5. None of the following:

```
INTERRUPTION_FILTER_UNKNOWN = 0
INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL = 1
INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY = 2
INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE = 3 
INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALARMS = 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in Xiaomi devices the System takes longer to activate the interruption filter, so you cannot ask  for the result just right away.
So, I sleep for a second and ask after that.
It also happens that sometimes it doesn't get activated at the first time so I have to call setInterruptionFilter a second time.

Something like this:

```
setInterruptionFilter(INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY)
wait
If INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY==getCurrentInterruptionFilter() then return OK
//Second try:
setInterruptionFilter(INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY)
wait
If INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY==getCurrentInterruptionFilter() then return Ok
return error
```